# Function does more than it's supposed too

Tags: c++

I am using x coordinates to dictate player movement.
`int xCoord=36;`
I call the below method once every cycle.
The only problem is that when called sometimes it will move the two spaces as it should and other times it will move much more for e.x. 20.

```
void game::processUserInput()
  {
    getUserInput();
      if(72-xCoord > 0)
        {
          if(isEventMoveRight() == true)
             {
               xCoord = xCoord+2;
             }
        }
       if(xCoord > 0)
        {
          if(isEventMoveLeft() == true)
             {
               xCoord = xCoord-2;
             }
        }   
   }
```

Comment: `xCoord-22` should probably be `xCoord-2`

Comment: Have you tried printing some message to the console from within the if block? That way you can see how many times the function is changing the value of xCoord.

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? What does `isEventMoveRight` and `isEventMoveLeft`? Also, the `== true` part is redundant and you can delete that.

Comment: the events are to detect whether left or right arrow has been pressed

Comment: Do the events reset after each tick?

Comment: Yes and it retrieves the boolean value everytime

Comment: @Tips48. I wouldn't delete `==true`.  Both ways compile the same  Without it it is not evident whether isEvent... returns bool, int, NULL, etc. Keeping it makes the code easier to read/maintain.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Actually, I disagree. Booleans should rarely be compared to true/false. Its like saying "is event move left is true" vs "is event move left".

Comment: @BWG You can name the function so that it reads more to your liking. What I'm saying is that when you first looked at this code you knew right away those functions returned a bool  and not anything else.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: that was implied by the "is" prefix anyway; other prefixes like "has", "num", "on", "get", "load" etc. all hint at the proper function usage.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code that could cause it to add or remove too much from `xCoord` - your obviously calling it too often as others have commented.  For whatever it's worth, your code can be cleaned up a bit:

```
void game::processUserInput()
{
    getUserInput();
    if (isEventMoveRight() && xCoord < 72)
        xCoord += 2;
    else if (isEventMoveLeft() && xCoord > 0)
        xCoord -= 2;
```

}